# problem unsetting quote (cart), data is not saved

Tags: cart, session, quote, magento1.7.0.2

I need to save quoteId and unset quote (cart) data in session clicking a button when I'm is in the cart, then after performing other operations (for example, I buy some items) I would like to click another button and restore previous cart using quoteId.

I've correctly got quoteId from session using `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId();`

Then I've tried to unset quote using

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
$quote->setIsActive(false); //tried setIsActive(0) too
$quote->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuoteId(null);
```

but unfortunately I still have a filled cart, in fact if I change page and then I come back to my cart I can see it (I expect that it will be empty after unset...), and on my database I can see is_active = 1 for this quote.

What I've done wrong? Can you please help me figuring out how to solve this issue?

Then, do you know how to load/restore quote from database and set it in session, so I can see it in frontend cart?

Comment: Is that a copy paste of your code, or a manual type out? `$quote->save();` is missing the brackets to call the function as opposed to accessing a public member.

Comment: thank you! I've missed the brackets, now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer for the sake of completeness...

You are missing the brackets for the function call to sale. `$quote->save();` is missing the brackets to call the function as opposed to accessing a public member.